# Obtain original colours from the cropped image yolov3

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, yolo

This is the first time I am trying out YOLov3. I am trying to obtain the cropped image within the bounding box predicted by YOLOv3. I am able to obtain the cropped image. The problem is,  the image is of a different colour than the original cropped image. I want to pass this cropped image into another model so that I can confirm that the cropped image does have fire in it.

I can't do that when the cropped image is different from the original. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the piece of code for cropping the image:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob
import random
from scipy import ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image


# Load Yolo
net = cv2.dnn.readNet("D:\obj_detection\yolo_custom_detection\yolov3_training_last.weights", "D:\obj_detection\yolo_custom_detection\yolov3_testing.cfg")

# Name custom object
classes = ["fire"]

# Images path
images_path = glob.glob(r"D:\obj_detection\test_img\*.jpg")



layer_names = net.getLayerNames() #Get the name of all layers of the network.
output_layers = [layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()] #Get the index of the output layers.
#These two functions are used for getting the output layers (82,94,106).
colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(classes), 3))

# Insert here the path of your images
random.shuffle(images_path)
# loop through all the images
for img_path in images_path:
    # Loading image
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=0.4, fy=0.4)
    height, width, channels = img.shape

    # Detecting objects
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 0.00392, (416, 416), (0, 0, 0), True, crop=False)
    # Syntax: blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, scalefactor=1.0, size, mean, swapRB=True)

    net.setInput(blob)
    outs = net.forward(output_layers)

    # Showing informations on the screen
    class_ids = []
    confidences = []
    boxes = []
    for out in outs:
        for detection in out:
            scores = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[class_id]
            if confidence > 0.3:
                # Object detected
                print(class_id)
                center_x = int(detection[0] * width)
                center_y = int(detection[1] * height)
                w = int(detection[2] * width)
                h = int(detection[3] * height)

                # Rectangle coordinates
                x = int(center_x - w / 2)
                y = int(center_y - h / 2)

                boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
                confidences.append(float(confidence))
                class_ids.append(class_id)

    indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.5, 0.4) #Non max suppression
    print(indexes)
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL
    for i in range(len(boxes)):
        if i in indexes:
            x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
            if x<0:
                x = 0
            if y<0:
                y = 0
            if w<0:
                w = 0
            if h<0:
                h = 0
            print("The box dimensions:",boxes[i])
            print(img_path)
            label = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
            color = colors[class_ids[i]]
            print("Dimensions of x:", x,",y:",y,",x+w:", x+w, ",y+h:", y+h)
            cropped_image = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            plt.imshow(cropped_image)
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 1)
            cv2.putText(img, label, (x, y + 30), font, 0.8, color, 2)

    img = cv2.resize(img, (700, 600))
    cv2.imshow("Fire Detection", img)
    cv2.resizeWindow("Fire Detection", 1600,1200)
    key = cv2.waitKey(0)
    if key == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The output I obtain is:

**Original Image:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xc7i3.jpg)

**Cropped image:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Y6de.png)

How can I obtain the cropped image as it is in the original image (the same colour)?

Comment: I understood how that happened. Apparently in OpenCV, images are actually represented in BGR order rather than RGB!

Comment: plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)) added this line and it works like a charm. Hope this helps anyone looking for help.